# Which word can represent X and O in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, word-games

In tic tac toe game, there are X and O's in boxes. How can i refer these O and X's? Maybe figure or value of box?

Comment: Please give an example of how you would use the term. These are values, figures, symbols etc depending on context.

Comment: I'm making a tic tac toe game. I want to name a variable that holds the value of O and X. For example box->figure or box->value.

Comment: Wikipedia uses marks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#:~:text=Tic%2Dtac%2Dtoe%20(American,a%203%C3%973%20grid.

Comment: Then i use "marks". Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for things in software is specifically off-topic per our [help].

Comment: @TonyK He asked for help in naming a variable. That is off-limits according to our [help].

Comment: @TonyK When he wrote [I want to name a variable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568049/which-word-can-represent-x-and-o-in-tic-tac-toe?noredirect=1#comment1409792_568049).

Comment: @tchrist: I missed that! Still, strictly speaking, the _question_ is still OK...

Comment: @tchrist If OP deletes the comment mentioning the variable naming ... does the question become valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always heard them described as [marks](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mark).

> a written or printed symbol:

Comment: Mark seems correct, thanks!